# HTML/CSS Logo with transparent background showing checkered background

Tags: html, css

When I've tried to put a logo with a transparent background I am getting the checkered background behind it as well. Is there something I have to do to make the checkered background in the logo have the same color as the background? I've tried multiple different images with transparent backgrounds to use as a logo but they all show the same checkered background.
[Picture of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5CFA.png)

Here is the HTML and CSS code:

```css
#grid {
    z-index: 10;
    margin:var(--twentypx) auto var(--twentypx) auto;
    width:var(--tenfortypx);
    height:auto;
    
    display: var(--grid);
    grid-gap: var(--tenpx);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 200px);
    grid-auto-rows: 200px;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "a a a a a"
        "b b b b b"
        "c c c c c"
        "d d d d d"
        "e e e e e"
        "f f f f f"
        "g g g g g"
        "h h h h h";
}

#a {
    grid-area: a;
}

#b {
    grid-area: b;
}

#c {
    grid-area: c;
}

#d {
    grid-area: d;
}

#e {
    grid-area: e;
}

#f {
    grid-area: f;
}

#g {
    grid-area: g;
}

#h {
    grid-area: h;
}

/* Presentation CSS */

body {
    color: var(--black);
    background-color: var(--white);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    
    background-image: url(../images/back2.jpg);
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#a, #b, #c, #d, #e, #f, #g, #h {
    z-index: 15;
    border: var(--onepx) solid var(--black);
    
    /* How to center text in a box. Comment out if not needed here */
    display: var(--grid);
    justify-content: var(--center);
    align-items: var(--center);  
}

ul{
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}

ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
}

ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

.logo img{
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Project 4</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    
    <!-- Set View Size -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link href="css/destyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/variables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    <!-- Google Font(s) -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon/favicon.png" type="image/png" sizes="16x16">
    
    
    
</head>
<body>
   
<div class="main">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="images/logo.jpg">
    </div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Styles</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Spa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Reservation</a></li>
        </ul>
    
</div>    
    
<div id="grid">

    <div id="a"></div>
    
    <div id="b">b</div>
    
    <div id="c">c</div>
    
    <div id="d">d</div>
    
    <div id="e">e</div>
    
    <div id="f">f</div>
    
    <div id="g">g</div>
    
    <div id="h">h</div>
    
</div>    

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `logo.jpg`.

JPG does not allow transparent backgrounds.

Convert it into `logo.png` first.

Comment: I tried converting it, but still no luck. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If the original image is JPEG, then after you convert it into .png, you will have to manually edit it and add transparency.

Comment: @Slash don't convert from jpg , convert from the original (photoshop or otherwise) image which has transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the background-color into transparent in CSS?

```
.log img {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: I tried doing that but, it still has the same problem. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

upload your logo here https://www.remove.bg/ convert it into png format and replace your logo with updated one it will work